# use array in custom filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I created an array that has the following format...

```
$scope.myArr = [arg1, arg2];
```

Now I want to create a custom filter that will take the array as a parameter and compare to another array, for example I want to use it as so...

```
<div class="form-container" ng-repeat="formblock in forms | filter:dateFilter(myArr)">
```

This way every `formblock` will be compared to the array, so if `formblock.date` has either `arg1` or `arg2` then these will show, otherwise hide everything else.

Is this possible?

Comment: check the updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your html with custom [Angular#Filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) should be

```
<div class="form-container" ng-repeat="formblock in forms | dateFilter:myArr">
```

**Your `forms` is passed as firsr parameter implicitely and passed the additional parameter with `:` after filter name.**

JS :

Filter :

```
app.filter('dateFilter', function() {

    var boolFound = false;
    return function(arrForm, arrArg) {

        arrForm.forEach(function(val, key) {
            var boolFound = false;
            arrArg.forEach(function(val1, key1) {

                if (val.date === val1) {
                    boolFound = true;
                }
            });
            if (boolFound === false) {
                arrForm.splice(key, 1);
            }
        });
        return arrForm;
    }
})
```

Here is the updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ue4sah4o/)