# How to filter with ng-repeat based on multiple values and specific string in it

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I'm new with angularJS and I have this data

```
 {
"name": "test product",
"slug": "test-product",
"tags": "tag 1, tag 2, tag 3",
"price": "80.00"
}
```

How can I use ng-repeat and filter based on 'tags' with multiple values targeting a specific string? I tried something like

```js
  $scope.filterTags = function (item) {
      return item.tags == 'tag 1' || item.tags == 'tag 2';
    };
```

```html
<div data-ng-repeat="product in products | filter: filterTags">
      <div>{{ product.name }}</div>
    </div>
```

I do get products with that specific tag but only when the value is starting with that specific string. Let's say products with a tag value of "tag 3, tag 2" doesn't get selected but "tag 2, tag 3" does. I want all the products with "tag 2" inside to be selected, how can I archieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [custom filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39279117/use-array-in-custom-filter/39279575#39279575)

HTML :

```
<div data-ng-repeat="product in products | filter: filterTags">
      <div>{{ product.name }}</div>
    </div>
```

JS :

In the controller :

```
arrFilterTag= ['tag1','tag2'];
```

---

```
    .filter('filterTags', function () {

        return function (products, arrFilterTag) {
            products.filter(function (val) {
                return arrFilterTag.indexOf(val.slug) > -1; 
//arrFilterTag['tag1','tag2']
            });

            return products;
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

The tags property should probably be an Array. If its not possible for you to change that you could split them by the `,` delimiter and then use that array to filter on which should look something like:

`data-ng-repeat="product in products | filter: {tagsArray:'tag 2'}"`

(not sure on the exact syntax)